# disable a field based on custom angular directive

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-directive

I can show/hide a field using custom directive like below

```
<button *ifPermission="permissions;mode:authMode">
</button>
```

Is there a way I can disable the element using the same ? I tried the below which won't work

```
<button [disabled]="{{*ifPermission='permissions;mode:authMode'}}"
</button>
```

Comment: If you type your question header into google first result answers your question https://medium.com/@tumma.suryaprakash/make-elements-disable-using-angular-custom-directive-29333e296993

Comment: I want to evaluate this directive =*ifPermission="permissions;mode:authMode" and pass the result true or false to disabled

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't want to parametrize directive to act as you wish in different cases?

Comment: This directive is coming from an externalized library that I am using in my app. I want to know if there's a way to achieve this in the app without having to modify the directive.

Comment: I'm afraid it's not possible. Directive is not a function that you can call, but a construct that you should use to change apperance of component. You can try wrapping *ifPermission in your own directive and introduce your extra logic there. Does it work for you?

Comment: yeah let me try that.  I wanted to know if this is possible. Thanks, That helps !!

Answer (score 0):

Directive is not a function that you can call, but a construct that you should use to change apperance of component.

If you can't modify *ifPermission directive you can try wrapping it in your own directive and introduce your extra logic there.

```
export class ExtendedDirective extends IfPermissionDirective{
  constructor() {
    super(/*  */);
  }
}
```